# Метод по подсчету положительных значений в соседних ячейках многоуровневой матрицы. Java

Tags: java, массивы

Два дня ломаю голову, не пойму, что не правильно работает...
Почти все время матрица просто обнуляется

Есть задача:
"Дана доска размером M × N клеток. Клетка может находиться в одном из двух состояний: 1 — живая, 0 — мёртвая. Каждая клетка взаимодействует с восемью соседями. Правила таковы:

Живая клетка, у которой меньше двух живых соседей, погибает.

Живая клетка, у которой два или три живых соседа, выживает.

Живая клетка, у которой больше трёх живых соседей, погибает.

Мёртвая клетка, у которой три живых соседа, возрождается."

```
    public void fieldReview () {
    int value;
    int [][] neighbField = new int[M][N];       // Создаем матрицу для записи результатов
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++){                // Делаем перебор элементов поля
        for (int z = 0; z < N; z++){
            value = neighboursCount(i,z);       // Считаем колличество живых соседей
            if ((field[i][z] == 0) && value == 3) neighbField[i][z] = 1;  //Если клетка мертвая и рядом 3 живых - она оживает
            else if ((field[i][z] == 1) && ((value < 2 ) || (value > 3))) neighbField[i][z] = 0;  //Если клетка живая и рядом меньше 2х или больше 3х жвых - она умирает
            else neighbField[i][z] = field[i][z];
            System.out.print(i + " " + z + " " + "count = " + value + " ");//delete
            value = 0;                                                                            //Обнуляем счетчик живых соседей
        }
        System.out.println();//delete
    }
    field = neighbField;            // Записываем обновленную матрицу
}
private int neighboursCount (int a, int b) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int x = a - 1; x < a + 2; x++){
        for (int y = b - 1; y < b + 2; y++) {
            if (!((y < 0) || (x < 0) || (y > N - 1) || (x > M - 1) || (y == b) || (x == a))){
                count += field[a][b];
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Зачем же так сложно

Comment: Записывайте результаты изменений в другой массив, а то во время исполнения другими ячейками вы используете уже измененные клетки. Также вынесите метод определения кол-ва живых соседей в другой метод. Слишком нечитабельно.

Comment: Все сделал, но проблема яснее не стала... Может, свежим взглядом яснее будет, что не так?

Comment: Так ведь я это и делаю..? Метод fieldReview идет по каждому элементу сетки, отправляя его индекс в neighboursCount, который и смотрит для этого элемента соседей только в радиусе одной клетки... Или я не понимаю чего-то?

Comment: Если Вам интересно, то что Вы описали - называется Conway's Game Of Life (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life)

Comment: Интересно! Спасибо! Это еще и тестовое задание на одну вакансию...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мда, а ошибки то спрятались. Насчитал две:
1) для определения того, является ли `[x,y]` координатами ячейки, нужно писать не `(y == b) || (x == a)`, а `((y == b) && (x == a))`.
2) вы постоянно добавляете одно и то же значение ячейки - `field[a][b]`. Нужно написать `field[x][y]`.
Вот рабочая версия метода, ошибки были только в нем:

```
private static int neighboursCount(byte[][] field, int a, int b) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int x = a - 1; x <= a + 1; x++){
        for (int y = b - 1; y <= b + 1; y++) {
            if (!(y < 0 || y > field[0].length - 1 || 
                  x < 0 || x > field.length - 1 ||
                  (y == b && x == a))){
                count += field[x][y];
            }
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

Comment: Даа, намудрил я... Спасибо, работает!